# compile sdl2 with c on linux using makefile gives undefined reference error

Tags: c, linux, makefile, sdl, sdl-2

I'm not familiar with makefile and just modified a predefined makefile for my project. i was trying to build my project on windows and linux. it worked on windows with no error but when i try on Linux all sdl2 functions give errors like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/scorepotion.o: in function `show_leaderboard':
/home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:263: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderCopy'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:273: undefined reference to `roundedBoxRGBA'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:280: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderCopy'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:282: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderCopy'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:283: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderPresent'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:284: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:323: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyTexture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:324: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyTexture'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:326: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderClear'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kali/Desktop/project/src/scorepotion.c:287: undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
```

in my project folder i have this folders: src lib include output
and in lib there are some libXXX.a files

this is my makefile:

```
#
# 'make'        build executable file 'main'
# 'make clean'  removes all .o and executable files
#

# define the C compiler to use
CC = gcc

# define any compile-time flags
CFLAGS  := -m32 -Wall -Wextra -g  

# define library paths in addition to /usr/lib
#   if I wanted to include libraries not in /usr/lib I'd specify
#   their path using -Lpath, something like:
LFLAGS = -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_gfx -lSDL2_ttf  -lSDL2_mixer

# define output directory
OUTPUT  := output

# define source directory
SRC     := src

# define include directory
INCLUDE := include

# define lib directory
LIB     := lib

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
MAIN    := territory.exe
SOURCEDIRS  := $(SRC)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(INCLUDE)
LIBDIRS     := $(LIB)
FIXPATH = $(subst /,\,$1)
RM          := del /q /f
MD  := mkdir
else
MAIN    := main
SOURCEDIRS  := $(shell find $(SRC) -type d)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(shell find $(INCLUDE) -type d)
LIBDIRS     := $(shell find $(LIB) -type d)
FIXPATH = $1
RM = rm -f
MD  := mkdir -p
endif

# define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
INCLUDES    := $(patsubst %,-I%, $(INCLUDEDIRS:%/=%))

# define the C libs
LIBS        := $(patsubst %,-L%, $(LIBDIRS:%/=%))

# define the C source files
SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%/*.c, $(SOURCEDIRS)))

# define the C object files 
OBJECTS     := $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

#
# The following part of the makefile is generic; it can be used to 
# build any executable just by changing the definitions above and by
# deleting dependencies appended to the file from 'make depend'
#

OUTPUTMAIN  := $(call FIXPATH,$(OUTPUT)/$(MAIN))

all: $(OUTPUT) $(MAIN)
    @echo Executing 'all' complete!
    $(OUTPUT)/$(MAIN)
    $(RM) $(call FIXPATH,$(OBJECTS))

$(OUTPUT):
    $(MD) $(OUTPUT)

$(MAIN): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(OUTPUTMAIN) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)  


# this is a suffix replacement rule for building .o's from .c's
# it uses automatic variables $<: the name of the prerequisite of
# the rule(a .c file) and $@: the name of the target of the rule (a .o file) 
# (see the gnu make manual section about automatic variables)
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@ 

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(OUTPUTMAIN)
    $(RM) $(call FIXPATH,$(OBJECTS))
    @echo Cleanup complete!

run: all
    ./$(OUTPUTMAIN)
    @echo Executing 'run: all' complete!
```

is the problem with makefile? how can I modify it?

Comment: You sure this `-m32` is what you want to do? Show full output of your make, along with output of `file src/scorepotion.o` and `file /usr/lib/libSDL*`.

Comment: Are you really trying to "compile sdl2" itself, or are you rather trying to build a program that depends on SDL2?  If the former, then surely SDL2 includes a build system and at least minimal instructions intended for Linux, such that you oughtn't to need to modify anything.

Comment: "The following part of the makefile is generic" seems suspicious to me.  I generally do not trust so-called generic makefiles, as they are only generic to project layouts and technologies that are anticipated by the author, and sometimes not even all of those.  And in a case like this, where the user is supposed to customize for a given project, it depends on the user to customize correctly, too.